# What HTML rendering differences exist between other browsers and Firefox?

Tags: browser, compatibility

I would like to know about the basic compatibility issues in the major browsers (Internet Explorer, Chrome) when compared to Mozilla Firefox, such as:

1. Text Alignment
2. Color
3. Font Size
4. Tool Tips
5. Paragraph Alignment
6. Text Bold
7. Shapes other than images
8. Line overlap
9. Table visibility

Thank you!

Comment: Rule #1: Don't use IE *anything* as a base, use Firefox for no greater reason than what works there will work in 90% of other browsers + the power of Firebug

Comment: WAY too many things to answer here, there are many good websites and books that cover these topics. Stick to standards and TEST whatever you make. If you have a specific problem there will probably be someone on this site that can help you with it.

Comment: Hi Jarret, Thanks 4 ur comments. It will be usefull 4 me if u list me out some basic UI issues which is more vital to trace out.

Comment: Hi annakata, Thanks and i agree with u and i edited the question as like u said. Now suggest me how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really vague question, but I find [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) extremely helpful with all aspects of browser compatibility.  Also look at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).

Comment: I was a bit confused by your answer until I realized that "Quicks Mode" is not the browser mode but a web site which compares web browsers ;)

Comment: Yes, it's an ironic name isn't it. :)

Comment: Thanks 4 ur valuable suggetions.But i have raised this question as an tester's point of view. Just 4 the intention find some BUGS.

Comment: Testing what? The biggest browser compatibility bugs have already been found.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain big enough that the smart people at Yahoo have written several CSS normalizing components for their excellent YUI library. Please see Reset CSS (developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset), Fonts CSS, Base CSS, and Grids CSS components.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur valuable suggetions.But i have raised this question as an tester's point of view. Just 4 the intention find some BUGS.